# gradle 2.2.1 not building with java 1.7 (or 1.8) on mac os x

Tags: java, macos, gradle

First off, I'm on Mac OS X, and I'm running gradle 2.2.1, at one point I was using a later version of gradle but I had to downgrade because I was having issues.

I'm trying to export a jar file from the command line (with `gradle build` or `gradle assembleAll`, I get the same errors with both), but I'm can't seem to get gradle to build with java 1.7 (or 1.8). I keep getting the following error:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
...
error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
```

so I tried putting the following in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

but then I get this error when I try to build:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Something changed the sourceCompatibility of compileJava. Expression: (sourceCompatibility == 1.6). Values: sourceCompatibility = 1.7
```

I checked that JAVA_HOME was set, and calling `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

I do not have a gradle.properties file in ~/.gradle/ but I tried creating one and adding the compileJava stuff to it and it didn't affect anything.

Does anyone know if gradle 2.2.1 has issues with java 1.7+ on Mac OS X, or how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing the JAVA_HOME and then building?

Comment: yes, well it was actually originally not set, so I set it to what it is now. i also happen to have jdk 1.8.0_66 and tried setting JAVA_HOME to this too, but it didn't work either

Comment: Can you try setting it to 1.7 and then build?